# how can i fix this error? this is what it says: : The type `EndTrigger' already contains a definition for `LevelComplete'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a game and this is my first one, but I'm getting errors and I have no idea why... I need some assistance.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

  bool LevelComplete = false;

  public GameManager gameManager;

  void OnTriggerEnter ()
  {
    gameManager.CompleteLevel ();
  }

  public void LevelComplete ()
  {
    if (levelComplete == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("HAHA... SO YOU THINK YOU'VE WON..??");
        Invoke("GlitchEffect");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change your local variable bool _LevelComplete_ to __LevelComplete_ or any other name than LevelComplete already used by the method

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually pretty clear if you read it:

Just rename either `LevelComplete` (the boolean value) or `LevelComplete` (the void function).

This is often solved by using a naming convention. e.g. variables start with lowercase `levelComplete` and functions with upper `LevelComplete()` - obviously this is not the only possibility.